# MSBuild - Set Build Definition Name As A Property

Tags: visual-studio-2012, build, msbuild, teamcity

My project team currently use TFS 2012 as our VCS and TeamCity as our Continuous Integration Server.

In TFS, we have multiple Build Definitions set up for each project and this collection include some bespoke/customised build definitions. Each build definition is driven by a unique build process template. Consequently, within each project, we have two or more customised build process templates, along with the out-of-the-box templates which include the Default and Lab templates.

We use TeamCity as our Continuous Integration system and this connects to TFS as our version control system.

Within TeamCity, I have set up a Build Configuration and Build Step which has MSBuild as the Runner type. What I am desperate now to pass to MSBuild is the name of a specific Build Definition from the collection detailed above. This build defintion will be driven by one of my customised build process templates.......not the Default, Lab or any other proecess template.

In short, what I'm keen to achieve is the ability to set a Build Definition name as an MSBuild property. It doesn't necessarily have to be from within a TeamCity context. If anyone can advise how to even achieve this from the command line, that would be perfect for now.

Comment: It should be the other way around -- the MSBuild is called from a Build Definition. If you want to kick off a build on TFS (using a specific Build Definition), you can use [TFBuild start](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337631%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) command. But then you will have to monitor when the build is finished.

Comment: If your are building using TFS, and TFS has CI builds... why using TeamCity at all?

Comment: Well Giulo, it just happens that a lot of companies implement Continuous Integration systems like TeamCity, CruiseControl, etc and each of these typically hooks up to a version control system such as TFS.

Comment: In our case, TFS is practically invisible to the project team, as TeamCity is literally the front-end tool. Let me reiterate again, we do not kick off any build from TFS so let me just re-define our requirement as follows. We want to be able to run our build (via MSBuild only) by setting a property to a bespoke build definition. Just assume that TFSBuild doesn't even exist, because it's frankly not even an option available to us (as it doesn't exist as an option in TeamCity).

Comment: As I stated previously, the simplest way of looking at this requirement is to consider a situation where I wish to run a build from the Windows Command prompt using MSBuild, which is very much possible. What I additionally want to achieve is the ability to set a property for MSBuild to target a specific Build Definition. I don't wish to consider TFSBuild, as TeamCity does not have that as a build runner option.